# Benchmarking Zend Framework with a plugin

Tags: zend-framework, benchmarking

I have created this plugin to benchmark the performance of my Zend Framework Project

http://pastebin.com/HD9MpRfR

One odd thing that happens is that sometimes the generated values are negative,

```
Unit: Microseconds 
Routing: 0.0013879999999999 
Dispatch : -0.477942 
Dispatch Loop: -0.470018 
Total : -0.430279
```

Why is this?

Comment: Nice work on that one, maybe you could move it to github so if someone has an improvement, we could submit pull requests.

Comment: Thanks markus, I don't have a github account, but feel free to do that if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is calling `microtime()`. I think you need to call it like this: `microtime(true)`. According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php):

```
If used and set to TRUE, microtime() will return a float instead
of a string, as described in the return values section below.
```

So, you are substracting strings every time. It might lead to strange results.

Also, check the returned `*Start` and `*End` values, maybe there is some problem in the logic of your plugin (I didn't review it in detail). An alternative technique could be to store these values in `Zend_Registry` instead of member variables. Maybe your plugin is being called several times, for startup and shutdown (this would reset the values of the member variables).

Hope that helps,

Comment: As far as I can tell, the plugin looks good, but you haven't been measuring time so far indeed! :)